# .htaccess rewrite rule without query string

Tags: php, apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us/([^/\.]+)/?$ home.php?id=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms$ home.php?id=2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ home.php?id=3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^help$ help.php [NC,L]
```

The above one is my RewriteRule 
When I call 'help' RewriteRule is working perfectly but the same about-us and terms not working.

Any mistake on my RewriteRule.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be a caching issue on the client side? Try disabling or clearing your cache and try again. If the issue persists, then you want to turn on rewrite logging on the server side and check in details what is going on inside your rewrite engine.

Answer (score 0):

The `-` character is reserved. You must replace or escape.

- Replace `-` with `_` which is a valid character
- Escape the `-` with `\`